# What is possible value for editor.insertSpaces other than auto

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I want to disable editor.insertSpaces

I want to keep tabs in vscode but I can't do it. There are no suggestion value for it except auto. How can I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these:

```
"editor.insertSpaces": true
"editor.insertSpaces": false
"editor.insertSpaces": "auto"
```

Comment: Great Thanks It's really work. Still wonder why it not exist in suggestion